# How to combine more than one count values?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a point CSV file with latitude, longitude and height information. 
As seen in the Output below code, where the count value of height is 1, 2, 3, 4 and 5.

```
df= pd.read_csv("point_25.csv")
df1 = df.groupby(["latitude", "longitude"])["heights"].count()
df1.unique()
# array([2, 1, 3, 5, 4], dtype=int64)
df1
# output
latitude  longitude
38.6287   -118.7425    1
38.6289   -118.7426    2
38.6290   -118.7426    1
38.6291   -118.7426    2
38.6292   -118.7426    2
38.6293   -118.7426    1
                      ..
38.6294   -118.7426    3
38.6295   -118.7427    5
38.6296   -118.7427    3
38.6297   -118.7427    2
38.6298   -118.7427    3
38.6300   -118.7427    2
Name: heights, Length: 370, dtype: int64
```

### What I want

If the count value is more than 1 then take the mean of all the heights and give one height value as output for a specific latitude and longitude group such that the count is 1 for every latitude and longitude.

Comment: hey @roshualine, have you tried anything yet other than `.count()`.  At first glance `.mean()` should return what you want.  It will return the mean for the ones with multiples, and the mean of one number is simply that number so that works for the single responses as well.

Comment: I tried ```.mean()``` but I didn't know how to combine it with ```groupby``` value. I was unaware of ```.query``` function as given by @Quang

Comment: Just do `df.groupby(["latitude", "longitude"])["heights"].mean()`  As it returns counts in your current code, changing to `mean()` will have it return the mean instead and the shape will be identical to your current output.

Comment: Yes, it returns the desired output. Didn't know it was this simple !! Its simpler and effective than the below answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I am reading the 'What I want' section correctly, I do not believe using `query` will be appropriate.  The rows that only have one count still need to be returned along with the mean value of the rows with multiple heights.

To accomlpish this the following should work.

```
df1 = df.groupby(['latitude', 'longitude'])['heights'].mean()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do `agg` and `query` like this:

```
df1 = (df.groupby(["latitude", "longitude"])["heights"]
         .agg(['count','mean'])
         .query('count > 1') 
      )
```